# why is the timer not getting back to zero when doing console in handlebackpress method even after doing clearInterval also how to avoid losing frames

Tags: javascript, react-native

I m trying to automatically start the video but before that implementing timer and clearing the timer was my goal. The countdown is getting cleared but the timer in the state in which my setInterval is assigned keeps on increasing even after been cleared. Also, ***there are a lot of frames dropped*** and **stutters** on each toggle even my code has become too messy I would really appreciate any kind of help that would help me to improve my messy code and avoid those dropped frames.

Thank you.

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {
        Platform,
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        BackHandler,
        TouchableOpacity,
        View,
        Alert,
        PermissionsAndroid,
        CameraRoll,
        } from 'react-native';
        import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
        import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

        const url = 'MY API';

        export default class App extends Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
            showCamera: false,
            cameraType: RNCamera.Constants.Type.front,
            recording: false,
            timer: null,
            count: null
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
            this.permissionRequest();
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.backHandler.remove();
        }

        async permissionRequest() {
            try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            {
                'title': 'Require Permission for Storage',
                'message': 'Storage permisson is required to store your photos in the gallery'
            });

            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                console.log('granted', PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS);
            } else {
                console.warn('denied', PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS);
            }
            } catch (err) {
            console.warn('err', err);
            }
        }

        handleBackPress = async () => {
            if (this.state.showCamera === true) {
            await this.setState({ showCamera: false });
            clearInterval(this.state.timer);
            console.log('this.state.timer', this.state.timer);
            // this.setState({ count: null });
            console.log('this.state.timer after', this.state.timer, this.state.count);
            } else {
            BackHandler.exitApp();
            }
        }

        async toggleCamera() {
            // console.log(this,'this');
            await this.setState({ showCamera: !this.state.showCamera });
            console.warn(this.state.showCamera, 'checking status');
            if (this.state.showCamera === true) {
            this.setState({ count: 10 });
            let timer = setInterval(this.tickingTimer, 1000);
            this.setState({ timer });
            }
        }

        tickingTimer = () => {
            if (this.state.count > 0) {
            this.setState({ count: this.state.count -1 });
            console.log(this.state.count);
            }
        }

        async takePicture() {
            if (this.camera) {
            const options = { quality: 0.9, base64: true };
            const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
            CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri)
                .then(resp => {
                console.log('resp', resp);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                console.log('err', err);
                });
            console.log(data);
            }
        }

        async recordVideo() {
            if (this.camera) {
            this.setState({ recording: true });
            const options = { quality: 'RNCamera.Constants.VideoQuality.480p', maxDuration: 2 };
            const {uri, codec = 'mp4' } = await this.camera.recordAsync(options);
            this.setState({ recording: false });
            const type = `video/${codec}`;
            CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri)
                .then(resp => {
                console.log('video resp', resp)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                console.log('err Video', err);
                })

                RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', url + 'upload', {
            }, 
            [
                {
                name: 'file',
                filename: 'filename.mp4',
                data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(uri),
                type
                }
            ]
            )
            .uploadProgress({ interval : 200 }, (written, total) => {
            console.log('progress', written, total, written / total)
            })
            .then(res => JSON.parse(res.data))
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(' server', res.file.URL);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('error ', err);
            });
            }
        }

        async stopVideo() {
            if (this.camera) {
            await this.camera.stopRecording();
            this.setState({ recording: false });
            } 
        }

        swapCamera() {
            const { cameraType } = this.state;
            let newType;
            if (this.camera) {
            cameraType === RNCamera.Constants.Type.front ? newType = RNCamera.Constants.Type.back : newType = RNCamera.Constants.Type.front;
            }
            this.setState({ cameraType: newType });
        }

        render() {
            const { showCamera, recording, cameraType, count } = this.state;
            return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {
                    showCamera === false ? 
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 50, width: 80, marginVertical: 5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5, backgroundColor: 'rgba(52,130,116,0.9)' }} onPress={() => this.toggleCamera()}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center' }}>Open Camera</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 50, width: 80, marginVertical: 5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5, backgroundColor: 'rgba(52,130,116,0.9)' }} onPress={() => this.toggleCamera()}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center' }}>Record Video</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View> 
                        :  
                        <RNCamera style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }} ref={ref => { this.camera = ref }} flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto} captureAudio = {true} type={cameraType}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginVertical: 20 }}>
                            <View style={{ flex: 0.3, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>starts in <Text style={{color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>{count}</Text></Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flex: 0.3, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View style={{ height: 60, width: 60, marginHorizontal: 5, borderRadius: 30, padding: 5, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'white' }}>
                                {recording === false ? 
                                    <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.count !== 0} onPress={() => this.recordVideo()} style={{ flex: 1, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }} /> : 
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.stopVideo()} style={{ flex: 1, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: 'red', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }} />
                                }
                            </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flex: 0.4 }}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.swapCamera()} style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Swap</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        </RNCamera>
                        }
            </View>
            );
        }
        }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        },
        welcome: {
            fontSize: 20,
            textAlign: 'center',
            margin: 10,
        },
        instructions: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: '#333333',
            marginBottom: 5,
        },
        capture: {
            flex: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderRadius: 5,
            padding: 15,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            margin: 20
        }
        });

// This is my package.json file
   {
    "name": "newApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.3.1",
        "react-native": "0.55.4",
        "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera",
        "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.0.0",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.13"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "22.4.4",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
        "jest": "22.4.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep timer as class object and not a state variable, try this

```
this.setState({ showCamera: false }, () => {
  clearInterval(this.timer);
});
```